# InvalidApnsCredential while certificates are valid

Tags: ios, ssl, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send a message to my push notification test app. It's been working in proof of concept several weeks ago on the same application but not anymore.

I get a failure: InvalidApnsCredential and Firebase tell us : ["A message targeted to an iOS device could not be sent because the required APNs SSL certificate was not uploaded or has expired. Check the validity of your development and production certificates"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42693019/using-data-in-rich-push-notification-on-ios-with-fcm)

But when I check in my firebase console, it tells me that dev and prod certificate will be valid for 9 more months.

What else could be causing this message?

Comment: check your apple apns redownload and upload the certificate to the firebase console

Comment: Simple and working :) Thank you !

Comment: I re-uploaded the certificate to FCM but still facing this issue. Please share the solution

Comment: My solution was to re download and re upload, nothing more to share on my end.

Comment: Same case here, reupload does not solve the problem.

Comment: Also, don't change the name of the key. I discovered that this was breaking it as I had many p8 keys from different companies I was prefixing them with the company. Don't work. Tricky tricky. Format should be ```AuthKey_{TEAM_ID}.p8```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In case if others are also facing the issue here are few tips:

1. Whenever you are stuck with notification issues try sending a push via the GUI console that firebase provide to send notifications
2. If your live app at Appstore is not receiving push notification but is receiving notification only when running via Xcode then you have not uploaded the production certificate to the firebase console
3. If you have uploaded both production and development certificates and still notifications are not received then download the latest certificates and upload them again to the firebase console

Comment: What if we're using P8 file, an auth key,  and still got this error `InvalidApnsCredential `?

Comment: Number two fixed my annoying problem! Again man Thanks! I should have noticed the difference between the "development" and "production" certificate

Comment: great ... it made my day... just resolved it using #2.. Thanks alot!!

Comment: We have the same issue with our P8 auth key. The whole error message is `{ "error": { "code": 401, "message": "Invalid APNS credential", "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED", "details": [ { "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError", "errorCode": "APNS_AUTH_ERROR" }, { "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.ApnsError", "statusCode": 403, "reason": "InvalidProviderToken" } ] } }`

Comment: @boog, make sure your bundle id doesn't have any typos.  In my case, I had one camel-cased and the other lowercase.

Comment: I have a working APN p8 uploaded to Firebase, then one day it stopped working. I confirmed all of the above, but it finally started working after I remove my old APNs and created a new one and uploaded it to Firebase.

Answer (score 6):

Adding Team id in Firebase worked for me.

> Firebase console -> General -> select your app -> Add TEAM ID

You can find team ID in Apple developer portal :

https://developer.apple.com/account/#/membership

Comment: how does this affect notification ? Do you have any explanation.

Comment: In my case, Team ID had a typo it worked after fix

Comment: Embarrassingly, this was my issue as well. I must have copied something wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This might pain you to hear, but it seems that the Firebase Cloud Messaging system doesn't like dashes in the bundleID. I had something alongs of my.app.bundle-y and I was receiving InvalidAPNSCredential message on postman... I eventually tried changing my bundle id to my.app.bundle when all else failed, and notifications started coming through.

This is pretty severe change, and only really reasonable if the app is not yet deployed.

If all else fails and you have a dash in your bundle id, then maybe give this a go.

Comment: This did it for me, I'd upvote you 20 times if I could.

Comment: The dash was the issue for me too. Even in development, you can't just rename it - have to go to https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list and create a new non-dash Bundle, delete your app & start it over again. The joys of development.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of uploading a .p8 file (APNs auth key), adding proper Key ID worked for me.

When you download the .p8 file from Apple. The filename will be in format AuthKey_XXXXXXXXXX.p8. The 10 digit(marked XXXXXXXXXX after the AuthKey_) is the Key ID you need to add.[please refer to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUlWS.png)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and was struggling to find a solution even when my APNs token were up to date and etc. I was testing on android before IOS and on the POST method to `https://iid.googleapis.com/iid` i left `"application": com.android name` instead of IOS bundle ID. just a stupid error on my side.

Answer (score 1):

in my case I was uploading .p8 key with wrong key id duoble check your "APNs Authentication Key" and make sure u have the right file with the right Key ID
and team ID

Answer (score 1):

In my case, The Apn .p8 file had been deleted from the Firebase console (and I don't know why! :| )
I had it before and just upload it and the problem was solved.
but if you don't have it, you can create a new one from the 
`Apple developer account -> Certificates -> Keys -> Add new key` and check
**Apple Push Notifications service (APNs)** from the services, then download it and upload in 
`Firebase -> App setting -> Cloud Messaging -> Apple app configuration -> APNs Authentication Key`

Answer (score 0):

The Xcode "Bundle Identifier" must match the one configured in Firebase.

**In Firebase:**
Project Settings > Your Apps > Apple Apps

**In Xcode:**
Your project > Targets > General tab > Bundle Identifier

Answer (score 0):

For my case, My team id was wrong in **Firebase APNs Authentication Key**

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, because I used the p8 that I created on
**appstoreconnect.apple.com -> users and access -> keys**
After a while, I remembered that this is API key not APN, and replaced it with a new one which I created on developer portal:
**apple developers -> Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles -> keys**
And it worked immediatlly.
Hope this will help someone out there.