# Why do I get the error "InvalidApnsCredential" for push notifications but certificates are valid?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am currently trying to send push notifications from a device to another but the problem is when I send a notification, I get the error "InvalidApnsCredential" and "Not registered", whereas my certificates are valid because I succeeded in receiving push notifications from Firebase Cloud Messaging.

In fact, this kind of funny because it was working yesterday and today it's not. So, I re-uploaded the appropriate certificates but I keep on getting this error "InvalidApnsCredential".

I don't provide any code, you can still ask it to me if necessary but I feel like this error has nothing to know with my code.

I would be glad to know if someone has ever experienced that before and know how to fix this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase : InvalidApnsCredential while certificates are valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43515467/firebase-invalidapnscredential-while-certificates-are-valid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a global issue of firebase. 
During the latest 3 hours this issue has been reported several times.

Please check.

https://twitter.com/ios_overflow/status/1156946303466844165?s=20

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I am serene knowing I'm not the only one who is having this problem right now. I hope this will be fixed soon.

Comment: i spent the whole morning uploading new credentials, although they were not expired until i saw that there were many people reporting this issue.