# iOS 10 FireBase when notification arrived, do not get call NotificationService.h Notification Service Extension

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, ios10

I use firebase and get successfully Notifications but when notification arrived,  do not get call NotificationService.h Notification Service Extension. 
I also set

NSExtensionPrincipalClass to NotificationService

NSExtensionPointIdentifier to com.apple.usernotifications.service

My notification is like

```
{   
"registration_ids": ["devicetoken"],    
"mutable_content": true,    
"data":{        
       "post_details": {
      "pcm_message": "asdf",
      "pcm_img_url": "http://portalvhds34w6bf5z9b21h.blob.core.windows.net/images/1519365008_5a8fab90cf683.jpg",
    }

   },    

"notification" : {
    "title" : "demo push",
    "body" : "this is push body"    } 

}
```

where is a problem or missing some information I have already set deployment target 10.0 in my whole project.

Comment: Hi ankur can you solved this issue or not now ? i have same issue like you  did not get call NotificationService Extension. please Help me bro.

Comment: @Hirenkanetiya ya tell me bro what is your problem 
I have solved out my problem

Comment: ,thanks for asking , but now i have solved this issue

Comment: @Hirenkanetiya I also solved. Using debug process I can debug My Notification.h 
How did you solved? 
I am not getting notification on time by using Firebase. 
did you get notification on time?

Comment: yes get notification on time but some time it takes 1-2 min .

Comment: in majority time I get Notifications by 3 to 5 minutes late.

Comment: your notifications format is like me that mentioned in my Questions?

Comment: please post what was the mistake

Comment: I am also stuck on this

Comment: hi @AnkurPatel can you tell me how you have fixed this, i was also trying to add the extension but my notification service extension is not getting called. I've added a question related to the same here. But no response as of now. Can you please help for the same.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51402054/rich-push-notification-not-working-with-fcm-in-ios]

Comment: i read your question but please use new method for notification service extension see i reply in your question